# How to architect a PyQt5 project using QML with multiple python files?

Tags: python, qt, qml, pyqt5

I'm just getting started using PyQt5 and QML and currently have a main.py file that has some simple code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    engine.load('QML/MainWindow.qml')
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

In my MainWindow.QML I have an ApplicationWindow, with a toolbar and a StackView that currently pushes and pops different QML files depending on button clicks, etc.

I'm curious if there is a proper way to use a Python file for each QML file sort of like WPF where there is Settings.xaml and Settings.xaml.cs. I would like Settings.qml and also a Settings.py file that would have models and logic compartmentalized for that page in it rather than having a massive main.py file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up solving this by doing the following:

Main.py:

```
def settings_clicked():
    stackView.push(Settings(engine, stackView).load())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)

    engine = QQmlEngine()

    component = QQmlComponent(engine)
    component.loadUrl(QUrl('QML/MainWindow.qml'))

    mainWindow = component.create()

    stackView = mainWindow.findChild(QObject, "stackView")

    home = Home(engine, stackView)
    home.load()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Home.py (first initial page in the StackView)

```
class Home:

    def __init__(self, engine, stackview):
        self.engine = engine
        self.stackview = stackview

    def load(self):
        self.component = QQmlComponent(self.engine)
        self.component.loadUrl(QUrl('QML/Home.qml'))

        self.home = self.component.create()

        self.settings_button = self.home.findChild(QObject, "settingsButton")
        self.settings_button.clicked.connect(self.settings_clicked)

        self.stackview.push(self.home)

    def settings_clicked(self):
        self.settings = Settings(self.engine, self.stackview)
        self.settings.load()
```

Settings.py:

```
class Settings:
    def __init__(self, engine, stackview):
        self.engine = engine
        self.stackview = stackview

    def load(self):
        self.component = QQmlComponent(self.engine)
        self.component.loadUrl(QUrl('QML/Settings/Settings.qml'))

        self.settings = self.component.create()

        # Attach to signals, etc.

        self.stackview.push(self.settings)
```

This will allow me to organize business logic into different Python pages and have separate QML files for the GUI.